# What is the >>Qt platform plugin "windows"<<, and why does it keep giving me an error?

Tags: python, visual-studio, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

I have had a problem with VScode and Anaconda when wanting to make a graph. I would like to graph data, but an error keeps coming up. I have displayed the code and error below.

**The code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

**The error:**

```
PS C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\Modelling-Cell-Growth-in-CFU> & C:/Users/.../Anaconda3/envs/rstudio/python.exe c:/Users/.../Documents/GitHub/Modelling-Cell-Growth-in-CFU/test.py      
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, windows.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

What does this error mean? What can i do about it? How can i fix it?

***Extra info:*** I am using VScode, with Anaconda. I am also using windows.

Comment: did you try the suggested resolution? e.g. reinstalling the conda environment? Also - the prompt you show looks like there is no conda environment active, so it might be the case that the path is not correctly sety up.

Comment: @LudvigH , i have accessed this through Conda. I can guarantee that this is through conda. I did follow the instructions, yet it did not work...

Comment: ok. did you try to reinstall the conda environment? a possible error cause is that you have mixed pip- and conda-installations so that you have a bad path. see e.g. https://forum.qt.io/topic/93085/qt-python-development-pyside2/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was that there was a Path error, as @LudvigH said. After trying to resolve all path issues, nothing could happen, so I had to delete anything attributed to Anaconda and Python. I had some mixed up paths with vanilla python, its pips and Anaconda.

A fresh download fixed the issue, and it is working now.